# Memory Management BSOD on Windows after swapping motherboards and RAMs, but the previous mobo and RAMs did it too. Ubuntu fine

Tags: ubuntu, memory, motherboard, bsod, memory-management

I have two Intel Series 4 mobos. One of them is Asus Z97-C, the other one is Gigabyte H81M-S2PT. So, when I first got the Asus mobo, I bent one of the pins and had to leave it at the shop for a month. So I bought a cheaper mobo, the Gigabyte one. When I got my Asus back, I swapped them. The latter worked for 4 years and the former gathered dust for years. Now, my Asus mobo had an issue. Whenever I added more than one stick of RAM, on Windows, it gave Memory Management BSOD. When I switched to Ubuntu I found out this is not the case with this particular OS. It worked fine. But it still gave Memory Management BSOD on Windows. It didn't even recognize the second RAM on Windows. I did a stress test and it never utilized it.

Fastforward to Thursday, when my mobo stopped posting. I removed the 4GB stick to no avail. I removed the 8 GB stick, and it posted and booted with no issue. Why? I was using the 8GB stick for years before that. I thought "Well, mobo must have bricked it" so I swapped the motherboards again. But I'm STILL getting Memory Management BSOD on Windows. Ubuntu still works fine. It's worth noting that I'm using another 4 GB stick of RAM instead of my 8 GB stick.

Could it be because I didn't reinstall Windows? Could it be that the 4GB stick bricks any DIMM that it gets close to? The motherboard is healthy, the DIMMs are healthy, why should Windows give Memory Mangement BSOD?